# JHipster generator: addMavenDependency is not defined

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to create a JHipster generator to setup Axon2 for the generated project.

In order to add a java library to the project I'using the function 
[addMavenDependency](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/creating-a-module/)  in the  [index.js](https://github.com/gdegani/generator-jhipster-axon2/blob/master/generators/app/index.js),

```
try {
            addMavenDependency('org.axonframework', 'axon-integration', '2.4.6','');
    }catch (e) {
```

but I receive the following error:

```
ERROR!
Problem when adding the new libraries in your pom.xml
You need to add manually:

"org.axonframework:axon-integration": "2.4.6",
 ReferenceError: addMavenDependency is not defined
```

Any help will  be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried derefencing `this` like this.addMavenDependency() ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the `BaseGenerator` and call `this.addMavenDependency()`.

Unless you are composing with another generator, then you can pass an object to be populated with the variables and functions being used by the generator like so:

```
const jhipsterVar = { moduleName: 'your-module' };
const jhipsterFunc = {};

module.exports = generator.extend({

    initializing: {

        compose() {
            this.composeWith('other-module',
                { jhipsterVar, jhipsterFunc },
                this.options.testmode ? { local: require.resolve('generator-jhipster/generators/modules') } : null
            );
        }
    },

    writing: {
        jhipsterFunc.addMavenDependency('com.test', 'test', '1.0.0');
    }
});
```